# How to Update Related Models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here in this documentation [Laravel Inserting Related Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models)
there is no method to update the current related model.
Have a look:
   [Relation Between two Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5hV1.png)

```
private function UserToken($token,$expire,$user_id){

    if($JetUserPass=JetUserPass::find($user_id)->token){
        $JetT = new JetTokens(['id_token' =>$token,'expires_on'=>$expire]);
        $JetUserPass2=JetUserPass::find($user_id);
        $JetUserPass2->token()->save($JetT);//NOT WORKING

    }else{
        $JetT = new JetTokens(['id_token' =>$token,'expires_on'=>$expire]);
        $JetUserPass=JetUserPass::find($user_id);
        $JetUserPass->token()->save($JetT);
    }
}
```

> Possible Error: Integrity Violation ...

Here in if block It is checking that the token is there for the user , if true then it will update the existing one,else it will create new. **I want to update the JetTokens Model from JetUserPass Model** i.e How to update Related Model?

Comment: @mrun That will not work, read the docs correctly.

Comment: It looks like you’re looking for Eloquent’s `updateOrCreate()` method. Also, please try to follow conventions for naming: methods should be camel-cased (`userToken` not `UserToken`) and it’s a good idea to return the related model to facilitate method chaining, or just to be able to use the updated/newly created `JetUserPass` instance further in the application.

Comment: @MartinBean here I have tried to solve the problem via many different methods works perfectly, but my query is how to update the model via Related model for example: "token belongs to user ". We can save the token via use of user model by calling the function ` $jetUserPass->token()` token function in user model :                                                   `public function token(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\JetTokens','jetuserinfo_id');
  } ` 
on this function save() is working fine but I want to update the existing record .  :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided the error message, I won't be able to help you out properly. But there is another method called `create` on the same documentation page. It says:

> In addition to the save and saveMany methods, you may also use the
>   create method, which accepts an array of attributes, creates a model,
>   and inserts it into the database. Again, the difference between save
>   and create is that save accepts a full Eloquent model instance while
>   create accepts a plain PHP array:

So, to answer your solution, you can do like this:

```
private function UserToken($token, $expire, $user_id)
{
    $jetUserPass = JetUserPass::find($user_id);

    $insertValues = [
        'id_token'   => $token,
        'expires_on' => $expire
    ];

    // Since you have same code, I have replaced it
    // in a single line following the principle of DRY.
    // Read the link below.
    $jetUserPass->token()->create($insertValues);
}
```

**Just a side note:**

Your code is violating the principles of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). This is because, your method's `if` and `else` block are having the same code except the `JetUserPass` and `JetUserPass2` properties. That should be avoided under any circumstances.

Hope this helps you out. Happy Coding. Cheers.

Comment: There is no repetition in the code , sorry but you didn't got the logic there, what is happening I'll Brief you – Here in if block It is checking that the token is present there for the user , if true than it will update the existing one,else it will create new . I know how to save new but don't know how to update the related model